# StreamWriter to do not write to file

Tags: c#, email, attachment, streamwriter, memorystream

I have a method in which I send File as attachment.
I use `StreamWriter` and `MemoryStream` to create attachment.
Code below:

```
public void ComposeEmail(string from, string to, SmtpClient client)
    {
        MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(from, to, "Otrzymałeś nowe zamówienie od "+from , "Przesyłam nowe zamówienie na sprzęt");
        mm.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
        mm.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
        // Adding attachment:

        using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(ms))
            {
                writer.Write("Hello its my sample file");
                writer.Flush();

                System.Net.Mime.ContentType ct = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType(System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain);
                System.Net.Mail.Attachment attach = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(ms, ct);
                attach.ContentDisposition.FileName = "myFile.txt";

                mm.Attachments.Add(attach);
                try
                {
                    client.Send(mm);
                }
                catch (SmtpException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

as You can see in these lines I write to "file":

```
writer.Write("Hello its my sample file");
writer.Flush();
```

While debugging I can see that `MemoryStream` has length of 24 ( just like length of string written to it).
But file received in mailbox is empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried closing the writer after the .Flush() ?

Comment: You don't need to use Flush on the StreamWriter,MemoryStream..Its redundant

Comment: @christian.s I can not close stream before I send a mail.

Comment: @Anirudha the `Flush` on `StreamWriter` is **not** (quite) redundant; there are scenarios where it adds data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try rewinding the stream:

```
writer.Flush();
ms.Position = 0; // <===== here

System.Net.Mime.ContentType ct = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType(
    System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain);
System.Net.Mail.Attachment attach = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(ms, ct);
```

Otherwise, the stream is still going to be positioned at the end, and reading from there will immediately report EOF.

Comment: Flush is redundant though

Comment: @Anirudha that's funny, because I'm looking at the IL of `StreamWriter.Flush()`, and it really isn't. Edge cases, sure. But cases.

Comment: @szpic aside: the classic analogy here is a "video tape" or "audio tape"; the problem is, a new generation of devs is now emerging that have neither seen nor used a video "tape" or an audio "tape" ;p

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm  not that young.  I still remember rewinding tapes with music of with games for c64 with pencil :>

Comment: @MarcGravell nice explaination.